# Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set

Tags: java, environment-variables, intellij-idea, maven

When I try to create my project's Javadoc in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven, the following error appears:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.1:javadoc (default-cli) on project spotify-web-api-java: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set. -> [Help 1]
```

`JAVA_HOME` is correctly set in any console window I open though, as `echo $JAVA_HOME` confirms. Why isn't it in IntelliJ?

Comment: I suppose this behavior is explained by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961615/unable-to-find-javadoc-command-maven#comment100306963_54323506) comment.

Answer (score 7):

This is because IntelliJ's internal consoles use their own environment. You can set variables for Maven in the settings dialog under `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Maven` > `Runner` > `Environment variables`. Add `JAVA_HOME` with whatever `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns in your usual terminal window as a value and Maven will be able to find the `javadoc` command!